# Introduce a Rlist in Python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2, wavelet

I am controlling R trough Python by rpy2 package.
Everything works fine except when I have to introduce some function arguments throug a **Rlist**.
Rlists are defined by the same keyword than Python: `list`; but its content it's very different.
Since Python believes I am creating a Python list, instead of a Rlist, an error is always shown.
I am using rpy2 to control WaveleComp R package.

Here I show an example in which I try to program `legend_params`:

```
import pandas as pd
# Import R manage tools:
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector, Matrix
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as ro
R = ro.r
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
grdevices = importr('grDevices')    

data = pd.read_excel('Data.xlsx')      # Load data
wvt = importr('WaveletComp')           # Import WaveletComp R package
# Continuous Wavelet Transform of the data:
cwt = wvt.analyze_wavelet(data ,'Valores',loess_span = 0.75, dt=1,dj=1/20,
    lowerPeriod = 2, upperPeriod = 30, make_pval = True, n_sim = 100)


# Create image saver
grdevices.png(filename="Subsidencia_Wavelets.png", width = 14, height = 6,
              units = 'in', res = 1000, pointsize = 12)
# Save image (here is where error is generated)
wvt.wt_image(cwt, color_key = "quantile", main = (trayectoria + ' - ' + agregado),
    n_levels = 250, show_date = True, periodlab = "period (months)",
    legend_params = list(lab = "wavelet power levels", mar = 4.7))


# Close Graphical Device  
grdevices.graphics_off()

Out[]:

  File "C:/Users/Dell/wavelet.py", line 88, in <module>
    legend_params = list(lab = "wavelet power levels", mar = 4.7))

TypeError: list() takes no keyword arguments
```

I have tried creating a Rlist through `rinterface`, but a Nontype Object is created, what also shows an error.

Continue the previous example:

```
import rpy2.rinterface as ri
ri.initr()

lista = ri.initr('ListVector(lab = "wavelet power levels", mar = 4.7)')
wvt.wt_image(cwt, color_key = "quantile", main = (trayectoria + ' - ' + agregado),
    n_levels = 250, show_date = True, periodlab = "period (months)",
    legend_params = lista)


  File "C:\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\conversion.py", line 60, in _py2ri
    raise NotImplementedError("Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '%s'" % str(type(obj)))

NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '<class 'NoneType'>'
```

I'd be really greatful with someone who could help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think lists are transferable

Comment: Maybe it works if defining a R List Type for `lista` . But I do not know how could it be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpy2.rinterface.initr` is used to initialize the embedded R, and you will not need to worry about it if using the `rpy2.robjects` interface.

`ListVector` is an rpy2 class, only visible from the Python side:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/vector.html#rpy2.robjects.vectors.ListVector

The constructor for `ListVector` works like this:

```
lista = rpy2.robjects.ListVector({'lab': "wavelet power levels", 'mar': 4.7})
```